# Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’ with a custom version of 'drop'

Tags: haskell, ambiguous-type-variable

I am an inexperienced Haskell user. I do not understand the error reported by the following code.

```
drop' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop' n xs = if n <= 0 || null xs
              then xs
              else drop' (n - 1) (tail xs)

main :: IO()
main = do
-- Using drop
   putStrLn "First, using Haskell's drop."
   print (drop 2 "foobar")
   print (drop 4 "foobar")
   print (drop 4 [1,2])
   print (drop 0 [1,2])
--   print (drop 7 [])
   print (drop (-2) "foo")
-- Using drop'
   putStrLn "Now, using drop'."
   print (drop' 2 "foobar")
   print (drop' 4 "foobar")
   print (drop' 4 [1,2])
   print (drop' 0 [1,2])
   print (drop' 7 [])
   print (drop' (-2) "foo")
```

Below is the error report.

```
inclass.hs:22:4-8: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      Potentially matching instances:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 25 others
        ...plus 17 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (drop' 7 [])
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn "First, using Haskell's drop."
           print (drop 2 "foobar")
           print (drop 4 "foobar")
           print (drop 4 [1, 2])
           ....
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do putStrLn "First, using Haskell's drop."
                 print (drop 2 "foobar")
                 print (drop 4 "foobar")
                 ....
   |
22 |    print (drop' 7 [])
   |    ^^^^^
```

The type declaration for drop' was copied from Haskell's drop function.
The use of Haskell's drop function in the program has been commented out
since it will produce the same error.

The program is being executed in ghci.

Simply stated, I do not understand the error. If only the drop' function is
loaded into ghci, the offending code associated with line 22 will execute
correctly. Likewise, Haskell's drop function will execute as expected.

Suggestion?

Thank you!

Seeking an explanation of the error.

Comment: You need to make the type of `[]` explicit, as in e.g. `([] :: [Int])`. Different types print the empty list in different ways (`[] :: [Char]` is an empty string and is printed as `""`).

Comment: `drop'` is a red herring. You cannot `print []` either, or `print (drop 7 [])` for that matter (unless you are typing it at the ghci prompt, where you can do all of the above).